# Define dummy variables from parameter list

Tags: yasnippet

Let's say I am experimenting with a codebase, and there's a function that takes a bunch of parameters, say

```
void foobar(char A, char B, int m, float k, int n)
```

I want to use the function somewhere, so need to pass these parameters to the it.  Does anyone have a way that they use to quickly create random dummy values (though determined by type) for a list of parameters, so that inputting the list would give:

```
char A = "g";
char B = "b";
int m = 14;
float k = 3.77;
int n = 2;
```

I've been experimenting with [yasnippet](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet), which seems like a great template system, with elisp support, so maybe it could work there.  Does anyone have any recommendations or a system that they use themselves?